# How to use !IsPostback in MVC 4 controller side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-state

In my MVC 4 application controller side how can use !IsPostback for checking checking UserId mange session or not. like below code:

```
        if (!IsPostback)
        {
            if (Session["UserId"] != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Users", "UsersList");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index");
            }
        }
```

any one have idea.Thanks advance

Answer (score 1):

you can check the url referer if it is the same of the current page or not

```
private bool IsPostBack()
    {
      bool isPost = string.Compare(Request.HttpMethod, "POST", 
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;
      if (Request.UrlReferrer == null) return false;

      bool isCurrentUrl = string.Compare(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, 
        Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath, 
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;

      return isPost && isCurrentUrl;
    }
```

Comment: #Fedri Qrueger actually my motive is first time user login after login successfully  i'm storing his/her userid into session then after any page directly run from my application im checking there userid manage session or not , if userid not in session then i'm redirect into login page other wise excution page, this kind of flow

Comment: then you might be considered using the custom authentication attribute.
http://www.bradygaster.com/post/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0 
and set on web config
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login" />
    </authentication>

Comment: #Fedri Qrueger  Sorry this is not a way what i'm exact looking , is there any other ways like above my sample code type.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is to split your code into two different functions by adding different http method attribute(s).

For example, this is an equivalent to *!IsPostback*:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Users", "UsersList");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index");
        }
    }
```

In ASP.NET Web Forms *IsPostback* is returning true, if http method is *POST*.

So *!IsPostBack* is for checking if request method is *GET* (but this technique is used in Web Forms not in MVC).